# cascade delete only transactional table in grails

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have a master table A (domain class) where I maintain a list of values (e.g. countries). This is associated with a domain class B (e.g. User) as a list and mapped through a join table.

When I do a delete of the domain B (by delete orphan), I want to delete the list of A items associated with B in the join table but grails (or rather hibernate) tries to delete the master records in Domain A as well which I don't want. How do I tell grails to stop the cascade behavior at the join table and leave the master table alone?

```
class Country {
  String name
}

class User{
  List<Country> visitedCountries
  static hasMany = [visitedCountries: Country]
  static mapping = {
    country joinTable: [name: 'Visited_Countries'], cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't add cascade. They should be deleted automatically.

Comment: @SandeepPoonia, Its true that on calling removeFrom method on user will remove the country associations for the above simplified example but I use delete-orphan because I have many associations and multiple hierarchical levels. This lets me use just the clear() method and hibernate can manage the deletion of items in that collection and their relations recursively.

Comment: @SandeepPoonia, I stand corrected. Removing cascade was the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So the problem was not the mapping itself but the cascade option I gave. What I believe is happening is when I remove the country objects from the relation list, hibernate sees those objects as orphans and attempts deleting them. Just removing the cascade: 'all-delete-orphan' solved my problem. I feel like an idiot but a relieved idiot who is a little wiser now and understands GORM a little better.

```
class Country {
  String name
}

class User {
  List<Country> visitedCountries
  static hasMany = [visitedCountries: Country]
  static mapping = {
    visitedCountries joinTable: [name: 'Visited_Countries']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to have Grails leave `Country` alone is to use a many-to-many relationship instead of a one-to-many.

When you think about it, a one-to-many proclaims that a `Country` cannot exist without its `User`. It would make more sense with something that's `User`-specific, such as a list of email accounts.

However, with a many-to-many, both domain classes can stand on their own. They can be related, but don't need to be.

```
class Country {
  String name
  static hasMany = [users: User]
  static belongsTo = User
}

class User{
  List<Country> visitedCountries
  static hasMany = [visitedCountries: Country]
  // excluded mapping since I don't know what it needs to be in your case.
}
```

You can see a comparison of one-to-many, many-to-many, many-to-one, and one-to-one in one of my [articles](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/grails-domain-class-associations/).

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel. I thought this was a good insight but when i tried this i got an error: "No owner defined between domain classes [class A] and [class B] in a many-to-many relationship. Example: static belongsTo = A". If i use a belongsTo, I would end up at the same problem I started with. And besides it wouldn't even make sense for my domain classes.

Comment: In a many-to-many, belongsTo has a slightly different meaning. In my example, it means you'd add `Country`-ies like this: `user.addToVisitedCountries(anExistingCountry)`. With a one-to-many you'd be creating a new `Country`: `user.addToVisitedCountries(new Country(name: 'whatever'))`. I think what you're looking for is a single representation for a given country in the database, while being able to keep track of visited countries per user. And that's what a many-to-many can do.

Comment: not sure if i understood this @emmanuel. If i put belongsTo (which means country cannot exist without a user), it will attempt to delete the country entries. That's master data for my application and I don't want it deleted. Only the association should be modified with the user rows.

Comment: That's correct when the domain class which has `belongsTo` does not have `hasMany`. That would create a bi-directional one-to-many association. But with a many-to-many association there's a mapping table which makes it possible for both domain classes to exist independently. Take a look at my article. When you see how a many-to-many looks like in the database, you'll have your "ah ha!" moment.